# Some numbers represented by symbols

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am trying to find some numbers that are represented by symbols, such as π, e, i, φ. I couldn't find more. Can you guys help me?

(English is not my main language and it is for school project.)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX!  $j$, one of the complex cubic roots of unity is another one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know about it. But do you know some other numbers like in Greek letters? Also I don't know much about complex numbers.

Comment: Not really at the moment, but I'll think of it.

Answer (score 1):

A good source is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant), but there are many more.

Answer (score 0):

This one isn't on the Wikipedia list of mathematical constants, it's the Greek letter Tau.

$$\tau=2\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

There are many more. $\zeta_n$ denotes $e^{2\pi i/n}$, an [$n$th root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity). $\gamma$ often denotes the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). $G$ denotes [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). In number theory, $\omega$ sometimes represents $(-1+\sqrt 3i)/2$, useful when we study the Euclidean domain $\mathbb Z[\omega]$.